# Glossary option in Search API indexed nodes

Tags: views, search

Does anyone know how to add glossary for search index nodes? In Views+Search API you dont get glossary option in contextual filters as you get in Views with content nodes.
Currently I am using grouped filter with each alphabet equal to title (trimmed to one character) but not very efficient way. Looking for a better approach.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the Search API does not support making a Glossary listing in a Contextual Filter. The best it can do is provide Facet Searching (after a search is performed).

Solr may support this using Shingles or something to help create the Glossary item, but no such Drupal submodule exists at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

this module can probably help some of you.
https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_glossary
It is working on D7 and D8.

Have a good day.